# Are there any real life instances of kidney organoid transplants in human?

Tags: medicine, development, kidney

Googling the terms "kidney organoid", "artificial kidney" etc. shows quite a huge amount of research papers regarding studies about kidney organoid synthesis from pluripotent stem cells and transplantation attempts.

But what I did not found (& my questions) are:

1. Are there any instances of successfully development and transplantation of kidney organoids in human beings? (yes/no)
2. If yes, then is it available as a therapeutic method? (yes/no)